# Placing axes origin at xmin and ymin

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, formatting, axis

How can I place the axes origin at `x=-20, y=2000`?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            legend pos=outer north east,
            legend cell align={left},
            grid=none,
            xticklabel style={rotate=90, anchor=near xticklabel},
            xmin=-20,xmax=20,
            ymin=2000,ymax=2300,
            axis lines = middle,
            %y axis line style = {stealth-},
            extra x ticks={0},
            width=8cm,
            height=8cm,
            set layers,
            x label style={at={(1,0)},right},
            y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
            y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
                scaled y ticks = false,
                set thousands separator={},
            fixed},
            x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
                scaled x ticks = false,
                set thousands separator={},
            fixed},
            xlabel={$m$},ylabel={$\bar{\nu}$\;(\unit{cm^{-1}})}, 
            style={thick}
        ]              
        \addlegendentry{$f(x) = 3.82379x + 2141.56$};
        \addplot[only marks, mark=*,scatter,domain=0:2000] coordinates {                
            (15,2081.78)
            %more and more coords
            (-15,2196.52)
        };
        \addlegendimage{green,mark=square}
        \addlegendentry{$R^2 = 0.998779$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell whether you mean (1) move the *y*-axis to the left side of the graph, or (2) you want the classic PGFPlots box with black borders around your graph. If you mean (1), then you can change `axis lines = left` instead of `middle`. If you mean (2), you can simply delete `axis lines` entirely.

[image: Two graphs, side by side. The graph on the left has the y-axis and x-axis originating from the bottom left of the graph. The graph on the right has the y-axis and x-axis as part of a box that surrounds the entire graph. The contents of both graphs are identical: a red point and a blue point. The axis labels are also identical on both graphs.]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            title=\fbox{\Large With \texttt{axis lines = left}},
            legend pos=outer north east,
            legend cell align={left},
            grid=none,
            xticklabel style={rotate=90, anchor=near xticklabel},
            xmin=-20,xmax=20,
            ymin=2000,ymax=2300,
            axis lines = left,
            extra x ticks={0},
            width=8cm,
            height=8cm,
            set layers,
            x label style={at={(1,0)},right},
            y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
            y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
                scaled y ticks = false,
                set thousands separator={},
                fixed
            },
            x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
                scaled x ticks = false,
                set thousands separator={},
                fixed
            },
            xlabel={$m$},ylabel={$\bar{\nu}$\;(\unit{cm^{-1}})}, 
            style={thick}
        ]
        \addplot[only marks, mark=*,scatter,domain=0:2000] coordinates {                
            (15,2081.78)
            %more and more coords
            (-15,2196.52)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            title=\fbox{\Large Deleting \texttt{axis lines} entirely},
            legend pos=outer north east,
            legend cell align={left},
            grid=none,
            xticklabel style={rotate=90, anchor=near xticklabel},
            xmin=-20,xmax=20,
            ymin=2000,ymax=2300,
            extra x ticks={0},
            width=8cm,
            height=8cm,
            set layers,
            x label style={at={(1,0)},right},
            y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
            y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
                scaled y ticks = false,
                set thousands separator={},
                fixed
            },
            x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
                scaled x ticks = false,
                set thousands separator={},
                fixed
            },
            xlabel={$m$},ylabel={$\bar{\nu}$\;(\unit{cm^{-1}})}, 
            style={thick}
        ]
        \addplot[only marks, mark=*,scatter,domain=0:2000] coordinates {                
            (15,2081.78)
            %more and more coords
            (-15,2196.52)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The first case fits perfectly! Thank you very much!